# Loops in a Platonic solid

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, euclidean-geometry, platonic-solids

For a given Platonic solid, how many closed paths are there on the edges of the solid if each edge can only be traversed once, and paths related by a rotation of the solid are considered the same?

For a tetrahedron, the answer is 2 (a triangular path or a path that touches each vertex once).  For a cube, the answer is 4 (a square, an elbow, a "U-box", or a zig-zag).  Haven't done the others yet...

Comment: Path related by a rotation, by an affine transformation, or by an automorphism? If you're only considering rotations then I would have thought that a clockwise triangle is not isomorphic to an anticlockwise triangle.

Answer (score 0):

For an octahedron, it's 5, since there is only one path for 1,2,3 and two different paths for 4.

For the dodecahedron
1 and 2  just the one
3  two different paths.
4  In a row, 2 (one pole to pole, and one other), one with the triangle, and one with a quadralateral, or 4 together.
5.